# How to create an event by a self-made control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on my first C# and .NET project that uses WinForms, as WPF would be an overkill for our purposes. I created a so-called ButtonMenu that comprises of all menu points, which are buttons. This class is derived from the Windows class Control.

One of the buttons of the ButtonMenu is the "Culture" button that, when pressed in this single-touch application, should change the language of all the forms the application has.

Originally, the ButtonMenu was just a kind of overlay class that accessed the controls of the BaseForm and contained methods. The BaseForm was holding the buttons inside a GroupBox of its own. Later, I run into problems with this kind of design and decided to make a separate control out of it.

My question
How can I create an event (or something similar to it) that can be caught by BaseForm, where the ButtonMenu is placed? The BaseForm can currently not react on this event and  cannot change the language of all its own controls, such as text fields and buttons.

Thank you for your help!

What I have tried till now is shown below. Unfortunately, I cannot reach the marked line.

```
    public class BaseForm : Form
{
    […]
    protected static ButtonMenu m_ButtonMenu = null;


    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        […]
        m_ButtonMenu = ButtonMenu.GetInstance(m_CurrentCulture, Size);

        m_ButtonMenu.Visible = true;
        […]
    }

    public override void UpdateWidgets()
    {
        […]
        try
        {
            […]

            // Translate button menu into current language:
            m_ButtonMenu.AdaptButtons(m_CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException aaore)
        {
        […]


        […]
    }

    protected void InitializeWidgets()
    {
    {
        string strMethod = Name + ":InitializeWidgets(): ";

        m_ButtonMenu = ButtonMenu.GetInstance(m_CurrentCulture, Size);

        SuspendLayout();

        Controls.Add(m_ButtonMenu);
        m_ButtonMenu.Top = Height - m_ButtonMenu.Height;

        ResumeLayout();
        […]
        m_ButtonMenu.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonMenu_CultureClick);
    }

    private void ButtonMenu_CultureClick(object sender, EventArgs eas)
    {
        int iSelection = listViewMessages.SelectedIndices[0];  // <<<<< NEVER REACHED!

        […]
    }
```

Comment: Too bad you're not using WPF. This would have been easy. I only partly jest and challenge your assumption that WPF is "overkill."

Answer (score 4):

Just define an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) in your class.

Whenever you want it to fire, call it.

```
// field
event EventHandler somethingHappened;

// in a method:
var threadSafeCopy = somethingHappened;
if(threadSafeCopy != null)
{ 
  threadSafeCopy(this, e);
}
```

Where `e` is an instance of `EventArgs` or a sub type of `EventArgs`.

Comment: I could solve my problem by the tutorial of MSDN at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx). I found out that because of previous considerations, my event publisher class called ButtonMenu was a singleton, which is no more needed. So, I modified it to a normal control class. I added all what is said in the MSDN site, and it worked properly!